# Auto row number in Jasper Report Table

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a table which have No, Name, Address, Phone, Email columns. I would like set auto number in `No` column without parameter passing form my java class. Is there `EL`or something to solve it in `JasperReport`. I am using version 5.1.

Note : As simple table, I did not provide the source and template.

Comment: No db, I pass, `Person List` as `JRBeanCollectionDataSource(personList)`.

Comment: Did you try to use *`REPORT_COUNT`* built-in variable?

Comment: thz, it is ok. I don't know which is built-in variable.

Comment: You are welcome :). [Using report variables](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-variables) & [JRVariable](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVariable.html)

Comment: You can also read the chapter ***6.3 Working with Variables*** of [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this

put a text-field and under the expression editor paste this `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` and save and run the jasper jrxml

`$V{REPORT_COUNT}` is a Built-in Variable.

Set the text field's evaluation time to "**Report**" if you're interested in the final value.

Comment: I get this ref, But, I don't know which is built-in variable. thz.

Comment: Is there any way to print it as alphabets.?

Answer (score 0):

We can also print alphabets instead of integer values. i.e. We can print a,b,c... instead 1,2,3...

For that we need to pass a List of alphabets which you want to print for sequence number, here I am going to use following code to create character list,

```
List<String> characters = new ArrayList<String>(26);
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z' ; c++) {
    characters.add(String.valueOf(c));
}                 
parametersMap.put("charactersList", characters);
```

Now, in Design add the following Expression to display the result in Alphabets instead Numbers,

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{charactersList}.get(($V{REPORT_COUNT}-1)%26)]]></textFieldExpression>
```

This will render the sequence as alphabets which is stored in List at given Index.